# Don't run rails server

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to run a server, but console show me an error.

```
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/execjs-2.2.0/lib/execjs/runtimes.rb:51:in `autodetect': Could not find a JavaScript runtime. See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs for a list of available runtimes. (ExecJS::RuntimeUnavailable)
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/execjs-2.2.0/lib/execjs.rb:5:in `<module:ExecJS>'
```

How to fix the issue?

Answer (score 1):

try to put in your Gemfile:

```
gem 'execjs'
gem 'therubyracer'
```

and after that do `bundle install` or only `bundle`

if you still have problems, delete `Gemfile.lock` and do again `bundle`

Comment: Deleting Gemfile.lock is very risky (unless naturally you are using git) as it will cause all the gems to be updated to the newest possible versions (including all breaking changes).

Answer (score 0):

Put in your Gemfile :

```
gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby
```

and then run `bundle install`

Answer (score 0):

On ubuntu I do:

```
sudo apt-get nodejs
```

That way I do not need to worry about js runtime across the projects